# xml marshaling and unmarshaling xsi:type

Tags: xml, go, marshalling, unmarshalling

This is about the **xsi:type** attribute, but if you have an element named <**soap:envelope** ...> similar issues arise where it seems necessary to implement custom unmarshaler functions.

here's the code with the problem (on the go playground: https://play.golang.org/p/ORQsINYS-9o)

```
type PayloadPublication struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `json:"xmlName"`
    XsiType xml.Attr `xml:"xsi type,attr" json:"xsiType"`
    Lang    xml.Attr `xml:"lang,attr" json:"lang"`
}

func main() {
    payload := PayloadPublication{}

    expectedXML := `<payloadPublication xmlns="http://datex2.eu/schema/2/2_0" xsi:type="MeasurementSiteTablePublication" lang="nl"></payloadPublication>`

    // 1. Unmarshal - 2. Marshal - 3. Compare
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(expectedXML), &payload)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err.Error())
    }

    result, err := xml.Marshal(payload)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err.Error())
    }

    fmt.Printf("expected: %v\n", expectedXML)
    fmt.Printf("result:   %v\n", string(result))
}
```

the outcome

```
expected: <payloadPublication xmlns="http://datex2.eu/schema/2/2_0" xsi:type="MeasurementSiteTablePublication" lang="nl"></payloadPublication>
result:   <payloadPublication xmlns="http://datex2.eu/schema/2/2_0" xmlns:xsi="xsi" xsi:type="MeasurementSiteTablePublication" lang="nl"></payloadPublication>
```

as you can see the attribute **xmlns:xsi="xsi"** was added which is not what I want

A workaround for this would be using a custom unmarshaler but this seems needlessly complex and verbose. (code below).
Is there an easier way to do this? What would be the conventional way to deal with this kind of XML?

workaround code (on the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/d4OtYPtYBDg)

```
type PayloadPublication struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `json:"xmlName"`
    XsiType xml.Attr `xml:"xsi type,attr" json:"xsiType"`
    Lang    xml.Attr `xml:"lang,attr" json:"lang"`
}

func (pp *PayloadPublication) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    // Attributes
    for _, attr := range start.Attr {
        if attr.Name.Local == "type" {
            pp.XsiType = xml.Attr{Name: xml.Name{Local: "xsi:type"}, Value: attr.Value}
        }
    }

    var dummy struct {
        // attributes
        XMLName xml.Name `json:"xmlName"`
        XsiType xml.Attr `xml:"xsi type,attr" json:"xsiType"`
        Lang    xml.Attr `xml:"lang,attr" json:"lang"`
    }

    err := d.DecodeElement(&dummy, &start)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    pp.XMLName = dummy.XMLName
    pp.Lang = dummy.Lang

    return nil
}

func main() {
    payload := PayloadPublication{}

    expectedXML := `<payloadPublication xmlns="http://datex2.eu/schema/2/2_0" xsi:type="MeasurementSiteTablePublication" lang="nl"></payloadPublication>`

    // 1. Unmarshal - 2. Marshal - 3. Compare
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(expectedXML), &payload)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err.Error())
    }

    result, err := xml.Marshal(payload)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err.Error())
    }

    fmt.Printf("expected: %v\n", expectedXML)
    fmt.Printf("result:   %v\n", string(result))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Technically the golden result in the example (I mean the [first one](https://play.golang.org/p/ORQsINYS-9o)) doesn't seem to be a well-formed XML. It has an unbound xml element prefix `xsi` for the `xsi:type` attribute. I think, [this spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#scoping-defaulting) sets the authoritative rule for that. This XML snippet looks to be taken out of contest, if it is a part of a larger document then the `xsi` prefix is likely to be bound elsewhere - it is very common for SOAP documents.

Note that the Go Marshaller produces a well-formed XML. This documents is still not a valid XML, because of missing DTDs in the snippet and so on, but it least it will not confuse any XML parser.

As a broader suggestion, matching the exact textual representation of XML documents for tests or anything is most likely to produce poor results, because there is more than one syntactically correct (and well-formed) way to encode a document in XML. Different marshallers can tweak the specific encoding approach to the liking of their authors, and this does not make the generated XML broken or incompatible with any other compliant decoder. Instead of comparing the text snippets, try to compare the unmarhsalled structures. Something like [github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp](https://godoc.org/github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp) package can make it simple.

Comment: I've also considered that the marshaler adds the xmlns:xsi="xsi" tag because it is missing from this example, but adding it in a higher level element, or in the same element for that matter did not seem to solve the issue. Could you provide an example in which this works? In my case I compare the text snippets because I want to build a library of structs not only suited for decoding, but also encoding xml to the same format. The xsi tag should look like this: xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

Comment: You can't force Go standard marshaler to use specific namespace prefixes for xmlns'es it generates in output. Note that this still produces compliant XML. You need to specify full namespace URLs in struct tags for that. Fully working example: https://play.golang.org/p/laS_hX9heyv